# Browser performance when combining image resizing with animated movement

Tags: javascript, image, animation, resize

I have been tasked with the job of converting a Flash animation into HTML. The animation is rather complex and requires the need to move multiple images (9) from location (x,y) to location (x2,y2) while simultaneously increasing the image size from 215px wide to 930px wide.

While doing some initial testing of this animation with just 1-2 images, I noticed a lot of choppiness in FF handling of this animation. To try and isolate the problem, I removed the dynamic resizing of the animation and just moved it from point A to point B.

What was interesting was that I saw the same behavior when simply moving a 930px image that was resized down to 215px (via the CSS width or inline width properties).

When I try the same animation with a different image that is actually 215px wide, it performed smoothly. I then tried the same animation with the original 930px wide image (with no resizing) and it performed well also.

This makes me wonder if the browser is having to "resize" the image down to 215px each time it is moved which is causing the choppiness. Is this a correct assumption? If so, is there any other way to optimize the animation to allow for simultaneous image resizing and image movement?

Notes:
1) One optimization I have done is to position the images absolutely in order to minimize the reflow process.
2) I have tested the animation using both jQuery and the fX animation framework.

Comment: Can you show some sample code on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) or another similar service?

Comment: I've run into this problem also, namely when I was attempting to move images horizontally. I know this is not a solution -- and I would love to hear a good solution -- when I made the images scroll vertically using a conventional scrollbar (i.e. animating the scroll itself) the images animate very smoothly.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I noticed this is extremely slow in MSIE.

Comment: Using Canvas is not an option?

Comment: Agree with Tigraine, I think Canvas/WebGL is the only route that will give you the performance you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly possible to achieve smooth animation with using of  elements. The best way to tackle with your problem is using combination of technologies: CSS Animations for WebKit-based browsers, -based animation for other modern browser (ff3-4, ie9) and possibly filter: transform() if you need ie 6-8.

Comment: Anyone have a link to a working example of MSIE filter transform() animation? Just want to see the performance.